# I tried to withdraw coins from Binance but they were lost on the blockchain. I need help from an expert

Tags: address, withdrawal

I really need some help from someone with a lot of knowledge and experience with crypto trading.

I tried to withdraw LTC from my Binance account recently, but I mistakenly used a BTC "receive address" from my Green Address desktop wallet, and the transaction didn't go through. I've contacted Binance and Green Address customer support several times and neither company is willing to help me recover my lost coins. Binance won't own the fact that they allowed a transfer that had an invalid receive address (the address started with a "3", not an "L"), and they said my coins are now lost on the blockchain.

Green Address says they don't have access to my private keys in order to help. I don't know how to access my private keys or even if they exist. I do have 2-factor authentication enabled on Green Address wallet. I've been told by members of this forum that I may be able to recover my coins if I'm able to convert my Green Address wallet to a cold wallet, and I have emailed Green Address with that question and am waiting for their reply.

Someone also posted that I try calculating an address from my wallet seed. I have no idea how to go about doing that and that's one of the things I need help with. I'm a total newbie to crypto trading and trying to understand all the technical steps is overwhelming and hard to comprehend.

[image]

I would be eternally grateful, if someone would be willing to walk me through the steps of how to recover my LTC coins?

It's a lot of money to me. I'm attaching a screenshot of the original transaction from Binance website, including the Green receive address and the Txid.

Answer (score 1):

> transfer that had an invalid receive address (the address started with a "3", not an "L")

An address starting with 3 is a valid LTC address, so Binance could not have known this is not where you want them sent.

In your particular case, recovery may not be possible without cooperation from Green Address. Green Addresses are 2of2 or 20f3 multisig addresses and require two keys to spend coins from. One key is from your seed words, and the other is held by Green Address, in the case of 2of2.

Unless you are able to convince Green Address to share that key with you, or sign a tx using it that moves your LTC, you will not be able to access the coins.

If you have a 2of3 multisig, you hold 2 of the keys, and should be able to use an Electrum-LTC client to generate the multisig address and use it on the Litecoin chain.

Comment: GreenAddress wallets are either 2-of-2 or 2-of-3. In the latter case, it is possible to recover (in theory) without GA's help.

Comment: Right, forgot they offer the 2of3 as well. I've updated the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a private key associated with the wallet address you sent to by mistake?

If you can obtain the private key, there is hope. If not, then I’m sorry to say all may be lost.

Answer (score -1):

Just dispute it from your bank. It’s not your fault that binance allowed it to go through. Or, it they can allow it to go through why can’t they reversed it somehow? Binance should have more security. It’s a lot of money on stake, and the only thing that I can see as a solution right now is to dispute all the money that you use to buy your coins. If binance can’t help you then you have to do it your own way. It’s the law you authorized the transaction, but you did not yet the value that you purchased.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! please remember that we have a [be nice](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) model.